# How to enable 3D analyst in ArcGIS through VB.NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.2, vb.net, 3d-analyst

I tried to create a TIN and suddenly an error comes saying "3D analyst is not enabled". In ArcGIS it can be done through managing extensions. How to do it through vb.net ?

Answer (score 4):

If your application is running inside of ArcGIS your product license should handle the activation of extensions for you. Failing that you can always use ArcObjects to check out the required extensions.

[How to use extensions (ArcObjects)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000033w000000)

> Extensions provide additional functionality to applications. Before
>   using the functionality provided in an extension, the extension must
>   be checked out, and when the tasks requiring the extension are
>   complete, the extension should be checked in. Unlike product licenses
>   that are checked out for the duration of the application's life,
>   extensions can be checked in and out as their functionality is
>   required.

Note: this all assumes that you have a license which includes 3D Analyst.